# calculating percentages on a pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe from the titanic data that I have pasted a copy of below. How would I add a column with the percentages of each bucket?

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what makes a single bucket in this case?

Comment: I would want 233/sum(count), 314/sum(count)..etc

Answer (score 29):

First a literal DataFrame with your input data:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("test").getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1,'female',233),
    (None,'female',314),
    (0,'female',81),
    (1, None, 342), 
    (1, 'male', 109),
    (None, None, 891),
    (0, None, 549),
    (None, 'male', 577),
    (0, None, 468)
    ], 
    ['survived', 'sex', 'count'])
```

Then we use window function to calculate the sum of the count (which is essentially the total count) over a partition that include the complete set of rows:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
df = df.withColumn('percent', f.col('count')/f.sum('count').over(Window.partitionBy()))
df.orderBy('percent', ascending=False).show()

+--------+------+-----+--------------------+
|survived|   sex|count|             percent|
+--------+------+-----+--------------------+
|    null|  null|  891|                0.25|
|    null|  male|  577| 0.16189674523007858|
|       0|  null|  549| 0.15404040404040403|
|       0|  null|  468| 0.13131313131313133|
|       1|  null|  342| 0.09595959595959595|
|    null|female|  314| 0.08810325476992144|
|       1|female|  233|  0.0653759820426487|
|       1|  male|  109| 0.03058361391694725|
|       0|female|   81|0.022727272727272728|
+--------+------+-----+--------------------+
```

If we divide the above step into two is easier to see that the window function `sum` is just adding the same `total` value to **every row**

```
df = df\
  .withColumn('total', f.sum('count').over(Window.partitionBy()))\
  .withColumn('percent', f.col('count')/f.col('total'))
df.show()

+--------+------+-----+--------------------+-----+
|survived|   sex|count|             percent|total|
+--------+------+-----+--------------------+-----+
|       1|female|  233|  0.0653759820426487| 3564|
|    null|female|  314| 0.08810325476992144| 3564|
|       0|female|   81|0.022727272727272728| 3564|
|       1|  null|  342| 0.09595959595959595| 3564|
|       1|  male|  109| 0.03058361391694725| 3564|
|    null|  null|  891|                0.25| 3564|
|       0|  null|  549| 0.15404040404040403| 3564|
|    null|  male|  577| 0.16189674523007858| 3564|
|       0|  null|  468| 0.13131313131313133| 3564|
+--------+------+-----+--------------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 6):

This is probably the option that uses Spark as it's most 'intended' to be used (i.e. it doesn't involve explicitly collecting the data to the driver, and doesn't result in any warnings being generated:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1,'female',233),
    (None,'female',314),
    (0,'female',81),
    (1, None, 342), 
    (1, 'male', 109),
    (None, None, 891),
    (0, None, 549),
    (None, 'male', 577),
    (0, None, 468)
    ], 
    ['survived', 'sex', 'count'])

df.registerTempTable("df")

sql = """
select *, count/(select sum(count) from df) as percentage
from df
"""

spark.sql(sql).show()
```

Note that for a larger dataset of the type you'd typically be processing in Spark, you wouldn't want to use the solution with a `window` that spans the whole dataset (like `w = Window.partitionBy()`).  In fact Spark will warn you about this:

```
WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
```

To illustrate the difference, here's the non-window version

```
sql = """
select *, count/(select sum(count) from df) as percentage
from df
"""
```

[image]

Note that at no point do all 9 rows get shuffled to a single executor.

Here's the version with window:

```
sql = """
select *, count/sum(count) over () as perc
from df
"""
```

[image]

Note the greater amount of data in the exchange (shuffle) step and where the singlepartition data exchange is happening:

Answer (score 1):

something like the below should work.

```
df = sc.parallelize([(1,'female',233), (None,'female',314),(0,'female',81),(1, None, 342), (1, 'male', 109)]).toDF().withColumnRenamed("_1","survived").withColumnRenamed("_2","sex").withColumnRenamed("_3","count")
total = df.select("count").agg({"count": "sum"}).collect().pop()['sum(count)']
result = df.withColumn('percent', (df['count']/total) * 100)
result.show()

+--------+------+-----+------------------+
|survived|   sex|count|           percent|
+--------+------+-----+------------------+
|       1|female|  233| 21.59406858202039|
|    null|female|  314|29.101019462465246|
|       0|female|   81| 7.506950880444857|
|       1|  null|  342| 31.69601482854495|
|       1|  male|  109|10.101946246524559|
+--------+------+-----+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have df with columns a,b,c,d for which you need to find percentage over the total of the respective columns. Here's how you can do this. This works faster than window function :)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn

divideDF = df.agg(fn.sum('a').alias('a1'),
                 fn.sum('b').alias('b1'),
                 fn.sum('c').alias('c1'),
                 fn.sum('d').alias('d1'))

divideDF=divideDF.take(1)
a1=divideDF[0]['a1']
b1=divideDF[0]['b1']
c1=divideDF[0]['c1']
d1=divideDF[0]['d1']

df=df.withColumn('a_percentage', fn.lit(100)*(fn.col('a')/fn.lit(a1)))
df=df.withColumn('b_percentage', fn.lit(100)*(fn.col('b')/fn.lit(b1)))
df=df.withColumn('c_percentage', fn.lit(100)*(fn.col('c')/fn.lit(c1)))
df=df.withColumn('d_percentage', fn.lit(100)*(fn.col('d')/fn.lit(d1)))

df.show()
```

**Enjoy!**

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to calculate percentage by dividing two columns then the code is below as the code is derived from above logic only, you can put any numbers of columns as i have taken salary columns only so that i will get 100% :

```
from pyspark .sql.functions import *
dfm = df.select(((col('Salary')) / (col('Salary')))*100)
df =df.withColumn('dfm',(col('Salary')/(col('Salary')) *100))
df.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to:
- calculate the sum
- create a `UDF` for finding percentage
- and add a column for the result.