# Finding percentages on groups in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a 2 different columns Gender and Country

Gender : Men, Women.
Country : America, India, Australia

I need to find out what percentage of men belongs to which country : India, America, Australia and also what percentage of women belongs : to which country : India, America, Australia in pyspark

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your current approach?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [calculating percentages on a pyspark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968946/calculating-percentages-on-a-pyspark-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
[
    ("female", "America"),
    ("female", "India"),
    ("female", "Australia"),
    ("male", "America"),
    ("male", "America"),
    ("female", "Australia"),
    ("male", "Australia"),
    ("male", "India"),
    ("male", "India"),
],
["Gender", "Country"],
)

df.show()

percent_df = (
    df.groupBy("Gender", "Country")
    .agg(count("Gender").alias("gender_country_count"))
    .withColumn(
        "total_gender_count",            
    F.sum("gender_country_count").over(Window.partitionBy("Gender")),
    )
    .withColumn(
        "gender_percent",
        ((F.col("gender_country_count") / F.col("total_gender_count")) * 
    100),
    )
    # .drop("gender_country_count")
    # .drop("total_gender_count")

)

percent_df.show()
```